# I/flutter ( 2680): type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hello i am new to flutter. i was trying to access folder name avialble in the device.i am storage_Path to get it.and this error came by.
My app try to fetch name of the folder in a json file.then the json file is decoded and pass to map variable.map variable is passed to a list variable which is return through future builder.but when i try to access the variable thi error occurs.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ext_storage/ext_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:storage_path/storage_path.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:permissions_plugin/permissions_plugin.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    Future<List> hello() async{
      String vidPath="";
      Map<String,dynamic> map=null;
      List<dynamic> data=null;
      try {
         vidPath = await StoragePath.videoPath; //contains vidoe path and folder name in json format

         map=await json.decode(vidPath) as Map;
         if(map!=null){
           try{
         data=map["foldername"] as List;
         print("has data");
           }
           catch(Exception){
             print(Exception);
           }

         }
         else{
           print("Null data");
         }
      } on PlatformException {
        print(PlatformException);
         vidPath =  "none";
      }
      print(data);
      return (data);
    };




    return MaterialApp(

      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar:AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 70,
          centerTitle: true,
          elevation: 10,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          title: Text("Cassette")),

        body:
        Center(
          child:FutureBuilder<List>(
            future: hello(),

            builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot){
            List<dynamic> msg=null;
              if(snapshot.hasData){


            }else if(snapshot.hasError){
            print(snapshot.error);
              Text("no data1");
          }

            return(Text(snapshot.data[0]["foldername"]));
            }

          )
        )
        ),

    );

  }

}

**Error

I/flutter ( 2680): type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast

**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the kind o json you would receive:

```
[
  {
    "files": [
      {
        "path": "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20190304_112455.mp4",
        "dateAdded": "1551678904",
        "displayName": "VID_20190304_112455.mp4",
        "duration": "7147",
        "size": "12787914"
      }
    ],
    "folderName": "Camera"
  }
]
```

so your code should be something like this:

```
String vidPath="";
List vidPaths = List();
  
      try {
         vidPaths=await jsonDecode(vidPath);

         if(vidPaths.length == 0){
            print("no data");
          } else {
            vidPaths.forEach((element) {
            print(element["folderName"]);
          });

         }
        
      } catch(e) {
        print(e);
         vidPath =  "none";
      }
```

Comment: How to access  data in "files" ?

Comment: instead of ```element["folderName"]``` you could be doing something like this ```element["files"][0]["path"]```